# How to find xpath of element which has entire text as dynamic

Tags: selenium, xpath

Here is example

```
<div>
    <a> Test </a>
    <a>dynamic text will be here </a>
    <a> Test4 </a>
    ...
</div>
```

and so on...

Here location of a tag with dynamic text in it is also not fixed and text in the tag is completely dynamic...

Can anyone help me to find the answer to above que?

Comment: If you place the html, we can find some other alternative way.

Comment: There are not enough details provided to get good answer. Share more specific HTML code sample instead of this simplified one

Comment: Need more info , share the relevant HTML

Comment: This is what interviewer asked me.. I answered to locate that particular element, iterate through the list of all <a> and then use text() or contains() to track down the element you are looking for. But I felt he was not satisfied with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find first div as an element, and from that elment list all childs bellow.

Here is an example code from head:

```
<div>
    <a> Test </a>
    <a>dynamic text will be here </a>
    <a> Test4 </a>
    ...
</div>
```

so code will go something like this:

```
WebElement divElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("div"));
List<WebElement> listA = divElement.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
WebElement elementDynamic = listA.get(1);
```

so you have all elements of  in one object so You can iterate, and do any necessary action You need.

hope it helps,